# create matrix from coordinate (x, y) ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, matrix

I can get positions of a [Matrix](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-build) with this code:

```
rows = 2
columns = 2

Matrix.build(rows, columns).to_a
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

this code is building a matrix from 0,0.

I would like build a matrix from 0,1

[image]

i would like to get:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
```

i'm using build matrix method, because is easy, we can use arrays to achieve the same result.

Thanks!

Comment: Your drawing seems to correspond to `[[[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 1], [1, 2]]]`, not `[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
rows = 2
columns = 2
offset = [0, 1]
```

simply write

```
ro, co = offset
Array.new(rows * columns) do |k|
  i, j = k.divmod(rows)
  [i + ro, j + co]
end
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
```

See [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new) and [Integer#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod).